# UIA AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler Memory Leak in Internet Explorer 11 on Server 2019

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, microsoft-ui-automation, windows-server-2019

Any time the UI Automation Focus Change event is hooked, Internet Explorer will leak memory with every page load.  This only happens on Server 2019, which is a serious issue for my clients who run thin clients.

Environment:

Windows Server 2019 Standard V 10.0.17763 Build 17763

Internet Explorer 11 Version 11.678.17763.0 Update Version 11.0.140 (KB4511872)

To replicate:

1. Put the attached code into a couple class files and compile to a console application.
2. Run that application on a Windows Server 2019 machine.
3. Start Internet Explorer and Task Manager.
4. Repeatedly load a web page and watch the memory increase every time.

I have two questions related to the issue.

1. Is there any known solution to this issue?
2. Is there an alternative to the UI Automation Framework which I could use to detect system focus change events?

I've tried adding a CacheRequest into the mix, but the issue appears to happen any time this event is hooked regardless of how the data is collected or handled.

```cs
using System;

namespace UIAMemoryLeak
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UIAutomationWorker worker;

            Console.WriteLine("Starting Watcher ...");
            worker = new UIAutomationWorker();

            Console.WriteLine("Subscribe Focus Change Event");
            worker.SubscribeFocusChange();

            Console.WriteLine("Watching ...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Automation;

namespace UIAMemoryLeak
{
    class UIAutomationWorker
    {
        public void SubscribeFocusChange()
        {
            try
            {
                // Hook Focus Change Event
                Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(UIAFocusChange);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private void UIAFocusChange(Object sender, AutomationFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do Nothing
        }

    }
}
```

Expected that there won't be any memory leaks.